# When trying to login to my hosted site using PHP, I get this 'Connection Failed' error message

Tags: php, mysql

This is my first time using this site so apologies if I break any sort of unspoken rules as a new user, but I have been plagued with a particular problem that I can't seem to find the answer to using Google.

So I am designing a website for a friend of the family and this site uses a login/account system with phpMyAdmin databases to store all of the users and check information when logging in. I am able to login perfectly fine when I host the website on localhost using XAMPP, however when I host the server on my domain and try to press the login button using the same credentials, I receive the following error message:

```
Connection failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

For reference, I am using Sentora to VPS host my website. I have exported the database I am using to store the login information from my Localhost phpMyAdmin into my Sentora phpMyAdmin. In order to connect to the database, I use the following code as an included PHP file that activates whenever a database needs to be accessed:

```
<?php
//Database Handler

$servername = "localhost";
$dBUsername = "root";
$dBPassword = "";
$dBName = "zadmin_barber";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dBUsername, $dBPassword, $dBName);

if(!$conn){
  die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Whenever I try to search up the cause of this problem on Google, I am only able to find tutorials for when this error appears when *logging into phpMyAdmin*. I, however, have no problem logging into my phpMyAdmin. I have tried changing the settings on both privileges and users in phpMyAdmin, but no combination allowed me to login with any credentials. For more reference, here is a picture of my phpMyAdmin users:

My phpmyadmin users:
[image: My phpmyadmin users]

And here is a picture of the privileges of the database I am trying to access:

Database prvileges:
[image: Database prvileges]

Comment: I have actually not tried using console to connect to the MySQL DB. I have been accessing it using Localhost and the Database tab in Sentora, which both allow me to access phpmyadmin. I will try this now, thank you.

Comment: looks like your db root user has a password.

Comment: Your root user has a password and you are not using it in your connection. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your picture there is no access to the database for Any users from the host "localhost".

It is not recommended to connect to DB without any password. Simply create new user with any username, assign it a password, make sure it is "localhost" in the host settings.

Then open users click edit privileges and give all the privileges to the database zadmin_barber

And one thing, don't use root to connect to database from your scripts. Creating user in MySQL is very easy.

Comment: Go to Home in your PhpMyAdmin. Then select Accounts. There select Edit priveleges for the user you want. On the next row to the selected Accounts go from Global to Databases, there select Database you want, select All privileges and just flollow the wizard.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response.
I did what you suggested to the best of my knowledge, I now have a user in my users tab that looks a bit like this:

User: Any | Host: localhost | Password: Yes | Global Privileges: All Privileges | Grant: Yes

I just used any password for the password tab. This user also now appears in the privileges tab in my zadmin_barber database. However, I am still running into the same issue. Is there something here I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: Watch this video it shows all you need https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yatPYO-rh4M

Comment: Just always make sure to create new user for your site, don't use root and don't use access without password.